# Repeat an element until it covers all the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to have an html/css element being repeated until it covers the the whole screen.

How can I repeat it and stop only on the screens height, but not repeat it forever?

```
#container{
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
}
.dotts{
 background-color: yellow;
 border-radius: 50%;
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
}

function repeat(){
 $("#repeating").append($(".dotts:first").clone());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`height()`](https://api.jquery.com/height/)

```js
function repeat() {
  $("#repeating").append($(".dotts:first").clone());
}

let fill = Math.floor($(window).height() / $('.dotts:first').height())
for (let i = 1; i < fill; i++) {
  repeat()
}
```

```css
#container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.dotts {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="repeating">
  <div class="dotts"></div>
</div>
```